# How does WiFi in android detect if the device has to sign in or not?

Tags: wi-fi, captive-portal

When the device tries to connect to an access point or router, it has to sign in on the captive portal page with the message saying

> "Sign in to Wi-Fi network".

How does the access point/router identify that a sign in is required for the device and what is the process behind it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The detection url differs between different Android versions.

For Marshmallow, it uses connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204, check the code here [AndroidXRef - Marshmallow 6.0.0_r1](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/packages/CaptivePortalLogin/src/com/android/captiveportallogin/CaptivePortalLoginActivity.java)

For Kitkat, it uses clients3.google.com/generate_204
check the code [AndroidXRef - KitKat 4.4.4_r1](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/CaptivePortalTracker.java)

Comment: I didn't want to hijack the answer by editing it, so I'll just leave a comment. It took me a while to realize that the detection URL triggers the notification if it **cannot** be reached. In addition, I needed my access point to respond to this request with some kind of content - in my case I returned a 200 code as well as the index page of my web server when /generate_204 is requested. Without content in the response, regardless of the return code, I would get a "Wi-Fi has no Internet access" notification.

Comment: @ubomb Seems odd, since `http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204` actually returns a 204 with no content, and obviously works. Maybe you just left out the `Content-Length: 0` header.

Answer (score 10):

This technology is called "Captive portal". There are several implementations. As I know, Android tries to reach a file named `generate_204` on one of the Google servers and if it is not possible, a notification in generated.

Further reading on Wikipedia: [Captive_portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)

Comment: Actually i know about captive portal. But i know the specific URL for check it. I want to know How it is work. Not what it is.

Comment: What do you mean - "how it is work"? Android sends a request, and if there is no positive response, it means that there is no connection to the internet, and notification is generated. That's how it works.

Comment: Which is the specific URL on which android request. I have mention in question.

Comment: In your previous comment you said that you know the specific URL. I think it's `https://www.gstatic.com/generate_204`

Comment: The URL seems to be http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 . Information taken from this site for chromium which is probably the same for android. https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/network-portal-detection

Comment: @Alex.S: I am not sure if it's relevant to ask this here, but I couldn't find a suitable place. Question is:  As you said 'There are several implementations' of captive portal. Some returns a redirect URL with a HTTP status code as 200/3XX/511 and some returns HTML page as such. These are known to me, but I wanted to know if you did find any link describing the types/methods of captive portal implementation. Are you aware of any test suites to verify if the captive portal detection covers all types of portals.

Answer (score 2):

A captive portal is generally implemented by directing all traffic to a valid HTTP response (200). This HTTP response is what appears in the captive portal.

This can be done with tools like iptables or dnsmasq.