# Change the server that Android uses for an internet connectivity check?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, internet

As far as I am aware, Android checks internet connectivity by connecting to `connectivitycheck.android.com`.

On one of the WiFi networks I regularly connect to, they use web filtering, and block the android website. This means I can use the internet, but when I move around the campus and my device has to connect to the next access point automatically (with the same SSID etc.), it refuses, as it could not previously get an internet connection. Provided I am rooted, can I change this server to, say, `www.google.co.uk`?

I am running Cyanogen Mod 12.1 on a C1905.

P.S. There is very little chance that I can get these guys to unblock the android website. :(

Comment: Just to be clear, a failed connectivity check is when you connect to WiFi but the `!` symbol appears on the WiFi icon on your notification bar

Comment: Technically, sure... Just add an entry in /system/etc/hosts file and reboot, but I'm not sure what it does to check connectivity, a simple ping or something more, redirecting it could cause it to fail on every network everytime. Remember if you flash nightly updates this will likely be written over each time.

Comment: In this case you can use some sort of proxy tunnel apps like psiphon, troidVPN, tunel guru etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute `su` then `settings put global captive_portal_server SERVER_YOU_WANT_TO_USE` in a terminal emulator app or ADB shell. I'm in China so I do this for every device I own when I set them up (i.e. clean flash - this persists through dirty flashing), and I use g.cn (shorthand for Google.cn). Google.com.hk *should* have the same function though I can't be sure.

I wonder why this didn't get a proper answer for this long...

Comment: Thanks! I too wonder why this went unanswered for so long. Is it just a ping it does? Or does it look for certain data?

Comment: It tries to reach a certain address for a "captive portal". More explanation in this question and its answers/comments: [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123129/how-does-wifi-in-android-detect-if-the-device-has-to-sign-in-or-not)

Comment: This requires root?

Comment: @Nimrod Doesn't seem so at least on my device, not sure if that applies universally.