# "Connected, no Internet" even though the connection works

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi

I'm running CyanogenMod 13.0 on my OnePlus 3. I have successfully connected to my home WiFi. I have proper networking. I confirmed it by successfully pinging `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Still, Android thinks the AP doesn't provide any Internet connection (`Connected, no Internet`)

How can I fix it? I have root access available. I'm not using Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your country banned access to Google, or at least its "captive portal" which is responsible for verification of network access on OS level. As I answered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134963/change-the-server-that-android-uses-for-an-internet-connectivity-check/154466#154466),

> Just execute `su` then `settings put global captive_portal_server SERVER_YOU_WANT_TO_USE` in a terminal emulator app or ADB shell.

For China using g.cn is alright, while for your country you will need to figure out a suitable captive portal. A possible list of that can be seen in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114041/150986).

Comment: I reside in Poland, so I'd see no reason why Google should be banned. In the router I have set up OpenDNS as my DNS provider. IIRC, it didn't occur under OxygenOS

Comment: Besides, I tried both `gstatic.com` and `g.cn`. On desktop, the `/generate_204` page generates the right code but the device still shows an exclamation mark.