# Android Chrome wifi “Sign into Wi-Fi network” how to disable redirect to www.Google.com

Tags: wi-fi, chrome-for-android

When I connect my Android device to wifi that needs login via web page Device has notification that says "Sign into Wi-Fi network".

Clicking on this notification automatically opens default browser (in my case Chrome) and redirects to www.google.com.

However increasingly more login pages do not meet Google's increasingly more stringent security requirements eg no https or certificate not matching domain etc and I can't login to page.

Instead I have to manually redirect browser to another page for example www.cnn.com to get redirected to wifi access point login page.

Is this a browser default that I can change? Is it possible to change default redirect page from www.google.com to say for example www.cnn.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134963/change-the-server-that-android-uses-for-an-internet-connectivity-check/154466#154466), if you're rooted,

> Just execute `su` then `settings put global captive_portal_server SERVER_YOU_WANT_TO_USE` in a terminal emulator app or ADB shell.

However, not all servers respond properly to HTTP 204 requests, so CNN might not be feasible for example. A possible list of usable ones can be seen in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114041/150986).

Comment: "Is this a browser default"? or does it come from the wifi sign-in?

Comment: @MarkW Unrelated to what browser you use - Captive Portal Detection is a built-in feature.

Comment: So it's handled by the OS?