# Prioritize cellular data over Wi-Fi

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, wifi-hotspot, data-connection, wifi-tethering

Is there a way to set the phone to prefer cellular data over Wi-Fi so that it will use cellular if it's good but Wi-Fi if cellular is not?  Similar to the "Switch to mobile data" setting but in reverse?

The intent here is while using internet as a passenger in a car and driving through areas where coverage isn't great, I bought a cheap prepaid hotspot from another carrier (that's providing the "Wi-Fi" referenced here), but I want my primary cellular plan on my phone to be used first rather than that.

Right now I manually switch between the two, but there are areas where which one is better changes quite frequently, so it'd be nice if this could happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not exactly what you wanted, but I experienced similar issues, and the way it sort of worked for me is either:

1. Ensuring the Wi-Fi is of such an excrutiangly bad quality so that Android thinks it's an Internet-less connection and therefore only drops to it when the cellular is at absolute zero.
2. To ensure that the phone thinks there is no internet over Wi-Fi, you could probably try blocking the URL it uses to check the connection, on your router. I remember there was a way to change the default generate_204 url in Android (see this: [Change the server that Android uses for an internet connectivity check?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134963/change-the-server-that-android-uses-for-an-internet-connectivity-check)) - change that to msftconnecttest.com/redirect or something that uses its own domain you're not afraid of blocking. (as the default gstatic.com is actually used for other purposes as well)